# SQL Server Select XML Column Based on Content by User Input Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am developing an sql server 2012 based application. 
I am a newbie to SQl server. But the requirement is to use it.
One of the table I am using contains an XML Datatype column. However the data containing in that column may vary as per the xml element. The only thing in common is the root: For instance this is a sample data:

```
<Tags>
    <key1>Value1</key1>
    <key2>Value2</key2>
    <key3>Value3</key3>
    <key4>Value4</key4>
    <key5>Value5</key5>
    <key6>Value6</key6>
</Tags>
```

What I want to do is to query the whole table and fetch records that will match a specific key and a specific values sent by the user.

Please assist me.

Comment: Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815836/how-do-you-read-xml-column-in-sql-server-2008) , [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195922/how-to-query-xml-column-in-tsql) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988122/how-to-query-on-xml-column-in-sql-server-2008) will give you a starting point.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: With the examples the xml element to query is known. In my case I do not even know which element is going to be queried. I do agree that the examples has given a clue on what can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Well it sounds like you need to use some variables to build an XQuery, yes? So, assuming you build a stored procedure or something which takes a pair of string arguments for key and value you could use the following example I've knocked up in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/faf9a/2) so you can try it out.

```
DECLARE @key nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @value nvarchar(20)
SET @key = N'key5'
SET @value = N'Value5'

SELECT 
    TagValue = T1.xmlcol.value('(/Tags/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@key")])[1]', 'varchar(10)')
FROM
    dbo.T1
WHERE 
    T1.xmlcol.exist('/Tags/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@key")][text() = "Value5"]') = 1
```

Comment: Although SQLFiddle has just died - hopefully not because of me! But when it's back up, it contains a working example including your example XML above from which you should be able to extrapolate a solution that works for you.

Comment: Cool. Would appreciate it if you accept the answer if it does the trick :)